# Problems when installing node-inspector

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js
I used "npm install -g node-inspector" to install node-inspector, but have following errors:

```
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspe
ctor\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


>C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\so
  cket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "D:\node_modules\npm\
  bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

>MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspecto
r\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bi
nding.sln]
>MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspecto
r\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bi
nding.sln]


    >C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector -> C:\Users\samsung\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js
node-inspector@0.7.0-1 C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-in
spector
├── debug@0.7.4
├── async@0.2.9
├── strong-data-uri@0.1.0 (truncate@1.0.2)
├── glob@3.2.8 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── rc@0.3.3 (deep-extend@0.2.6, ini@1.1.0, optimist@0.3.7)
├── express@3.4.8 (methods@0.1.0, fresh@0.2.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, merge-desc
riptors@0.0.1, range-parser@0.0.4, cookie@0.1.0, cookie-signature@1.0.1, mkdirp@
0.3.5, commander@1.3.2, send@0.1.4, connect@2.12.0)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.i
o-client@0.9.16)
```

I may want to know how can I deal with it? Thanks!I have successfully use "npm install express" to install express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, that's normal on Windows systems. I get the same warnings while installing it, and it works just fine:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector -> C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js
node-inspector@0.7.0-1 C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector
└── ...dependencies

C:\Users\gustavo
λ node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.7.0-1
   info  - socket.io started
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

Try to execute `node-inspector` yourself ;)

Also, if the `npm install` command didn't finished with explicit errors, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the node modules have to be compiled depending upon the OS. `node-gyp` takes care of this, but this needs a C++ runtime.

So make sure that you have some C++ library installed. See the installation instructions for Windows at https://npmjs.org/package/node-gyp

Comment: I have the same issue and already have C++ redist. installed.